# Is the Android Emulator supposed to take this long to load? 20 minutes and still just the Android screen

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, emulation

I've tried making 3 different emulators but haven't managed to get any of them to actually load. They all just get stuck on the screen with "Android" written across it. Am I being too impatient? It has been 20 minutes now and the emulator still hasn't turned on.

I'm using Eclipse btw, it gets stuck here:

```
[2015-06-02 11:36:10 - my-gdx-game-android] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

in the console. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can use third party emulator like [bluestack](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluestacks.com%2Fdownload.html&ei=wIttVbqPN6K1mwWy64CgCA&usg=AFQjCNFOEqtQPOnoJtFCwUi02nzbWlIZYA&sig2=ACL9S3TpqqsmpQz5h7ppxA&bvm=bv.94455598,d.dGY) or [jar of beans](http://www.bestandroidemulator.com/jar-beans-android-emulator/)

Answer (score 0):

Android emulator is very slow by its nature, but you can speed it up activating [Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration).

Also, you can try another emulator or update your project to Android Studio, with a faster emulator. By the way, ADT is obsolete and you should use Android Studio.

Also, read this questions and its replies:

> [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Use **Genymotion Emulator** it's based on virtual box.

even i can run 3 emulators in the same time.

make an account on genymotion site and download it

download link **[genymotion site](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download)**

[image]